Erro: tentativa de usar um nome de variável com comprimento zero
Em R, o que a mensagem Erro: tentativa de usar um nome de variável com comprimento zero significa?
Tenho o trecho abaixo em um arquivo Rmarkdown em Rstudio:
```
population.values <- c(11, 14, 17)

sample.size <- 2

distribution <- expand.grid(first.pick=population.values, second.pick=population.values)
```

Quando tento executar, ele falha com este erro:
> ```
Erro: tentativa de usar um nome de variável com comprimento zero

Não entendo o que essa mensagem significa, ou por que está ocorrendo aqui. Qual pode ser a causa disso?

O que este erro significa
Em R, é possível criar variáveis cujos nomes contenham espaços, pontuação, parênteses etc. Para fazer isso, utilizamos acentos graves (`) ao redor do nome da variável:
> `variável com espaço e caractgeres especiais no nome (??!!)` <- 1
> print(`variável com espaço e caractgeres especiais no nome (??!!)`)
[1] 1

Há, porém, uma restrição: o nome da variável precisa conter um caractere ao menos:
> `` <- 1
Erro: tentativa de usar um nome de variável com comprimento zero

Como ` é usado em Markdown, isso pode levar a situações confusas. Vejamos alguns casos.
"Tag" {r} não adicionada
No caso da pergunta, esqueceu-se de adicionar {r}  depois do primeiro ```. Se alterado conforme abaixo, funciona:
```{r}
population.values <- c(11, 14, 17)

sample.size <- 2

distribution <- expand.grid(first.pick=population.values, second.pick=population.values)
```

Tentar executar a linha ```{r}
Se você estiver com o cursor na linha ```{r} e pressionar Ctrl+Enter, vai receber essa mesma mensagem de erro. Apenas mova o cursor para a linha dentro do bloco que você deseja executar.
Tentar executar arquivo Rmarkdown como script R
Os arquivos Rmarkdown incluem, naturalmente, documentação, além do código. Se tentar executá-los apenas como código e, por exemplo, houver um bloco no começo do arquivo, essa mensagem de erro pode aparecer. Isso acontece, por exemplo, se tentar rodar algo como R arquivo.Rmd no terminal, ou selecionar o conteúdo todo do artigo no Rstudio e pressionar Ctrl+Enter.
Esquecer um acento no ``` final
Se você colocar um backtick a menos no final do bloco, como abaixo...
```{r}
a <- 1

``

e executar Run current chunk, este erro acontecerá.
Estes são apenas alguns exemplos. As causas possíveis são inúmeras! Em alguns casos, podem até ser bugs em algum pacote. Ainda assim, é possível que ter esses casos em mente ajude a clarificar o que está acontecendo.
